# Actualización List en clases java

Tags: arraylist

El problema que estoy teniendo es que al dar de alta un Course, le asigno un Boss. pues bien, no se como actualizar el arraylist

Con el siguiente método cuando asigno un nuevo Course a uno de los Boss creados, quiero actualizar el ArrayList listCourse, pero no lo hace correctamente ya que asigna todos los Course a todos los Boss.

```
public void addNewCourse(List dataList) {
        do {
                System.out.print("Id del Indice: ");
                int idCourse = Principal.scan.nextInt();
                Principal.scan.nextLine();                                     
                System.out.print("Introduce El nombre del Indice: ");
                String courseName = Principal.scan.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Introduce el Code del Jefe de estudios: ");
                int index = Principal.scan.nextInt();
                //index = index - 1;
               if(index >= dataList.size()) {
                    System.out.println("El Code introducido no existe");
                    break;
                }else if (dataList.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println("No hay Jefes de estudios dados de alta. No puedes añadir Indice.");
                    break;
                }
                Boss boss = (Boss)dataList.get(index);
                 System.out.println(boss);
                Course course = new Course(idCourse, courseName, boss);
                if (listCourse.contains(course)) {
                    System.out.println("Identificacion repetida. EL Id (" + idCourse + ") ya ha sido dado de alta.");
                } else {
                    Iterator<Course> iterator = listCourse.iterator();  
                    Course c = null;                                     
                    boolean found = false;                              

                    while (iterator.hasNext() && !found) {                
                        c = iterator.next();
                        if (c.getId() == course.getId()) {
                            found = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (found) {
                        System.out.println("EL id (" + course.getId() + ") ya existe");    
                    } else {                                                                   
                        listCourse.add(course);                 /
                        course.setBoss(this);
                        boss.setListCourse(listCourse);  //Entiendo que aquí está el problema
                        System.out.println(Menu.blue+"Indice: " + course.getCourseName() + " dado de alta"+Menu.reset);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }while(true);
    }
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo el código, parece que el error está en la línea donde se hace `boss.setListCourse(listCourse);`. Cada vez que se llama al método `setListCourse` se está sobreescribiendo toda la lista anterior incluyendo los cursos asignados a otros jefes.

En lugar de eso, lo que puedes hacer, es que cuando crees el objeto Course, lo añadas a la lista de cursos del Boss al que se lo asignaste. Para ello cambia la línea `boss.setListCourse(listCourse);` por la siguiente:

```
boss.addCourse(course);
```

Comment: Gracias funciona perfectamente. Ahora el problema lo tengo al eliminar el Course que lo elimina correctamente, sin embargo en el listado de Boss sigue apareciendo. Te muestro el métiodo que utilizo para eliminael el Course de la List